# How can I construct a datetime object with 6 integers?

Tags: php, datetime, date, datetime-format

I have problems with

```
new Datetime($year."-".$month."-".$day." ".$hour.":".$minute.":"."00")
```

how would you construct a datetime with integers?

Comment: There are only 5 variables, your question asks about using 6 (integers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, using **6 integers** as asked would be to use `DateTime`'s [`setDate()`](http://php.net/datetime.setdate) and [`setTime()`](http://php.net/datetime.settime) methods.

```
$date = date_create()->setDate($year, $month, $day)
                     ->setTime($hour, $minute, $second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, you are missing a dot (.) before $month. Try this:

```
new Datetime($year."-".$month."-".$day." ".$hour.":".$minute)
```

Comment: +1 to offset @JeffPigarelli's -1, since this is a valid answer.  This code already works just fine for creating a `DateTime` from a set of integers.

Answer (score 0):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

That's pretty much what mktime is for.  Then, of course, convert to DateTime, presuming PHP 5.3+.

Comment: `DateTime` has been around since PHP 5.2.0, though of course there were new features added in 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

This Works

```
$year =2012 ; $month =4 ;$day = 26 ; $hour = 6 ; $minute =30 ; $sec = 3;
$date = sprintf("%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d",$year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$sec);
$dateTime = new Datetime($date);
var_dump($dateTime);
```

Output

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2012-04-26 06:30:03' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
```

Comment: spaghetti code reminds me of spaghetti cat. I'll just play that song